# Suitable Datastructure for a bookstore

Tags: data-structures

How can I build a datastructure that helps me query products based on their category, title, author etc.

```
ItemNo , Product No (unique), Title, Author, Category 
1 , 00000001, Programming Interview, Olivier , Books > Business, Finance & Law > Careers > Job Hunting 
2 , 000002, The Art of Captaincy, Robert James, Books > Biography > Sport > Cricket
```

What is the best way to do this - (this is not for homework or assignment)

Comment: How many books are you talking about here? The best general solution would be a relational database, but if your data set is reasonably small then a sequential search would be plenty fast. If your data set is larger and you must do it in memory, then you need to look into keyed data structures like hash maps or trees.

Comment: For storing around 10,000 books but I am looking for an in memory solution that is scalable for 100,000 or more books and more clever than a linear search.

Answer (score 0):

If you need queries based on so many different categories, a relational database seems the right tool. You also get ACID for free.

Of course, you could also maintain a lot of maps from all columns you want to index to your products.

Comment: Which datastructures ? Thats what I wanted to know. Specially for categories and sub categories ?